# Adding an object at a specific index of an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, foundation

How can an object be added at a specific index of an `NSMutableArray`?

How is an object added to the front of the array?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:42];
```

To add an object to the front of the array, use 0 as the index:

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];
```

Comment: What if i try to run first statement on a newly allocated mutable array with currently no data in it?

Answer (score 44):

Take a look at the `insertObject:atIndex:` method of the [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Adding to the "front" of the array implies index 0.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[array addObject:@"b"]; // Contains "b"
[array insertObject:@"a" atIndex:0]; // Contains "a", "b"
[array insertObject:@"c" atIndex:2]; // Contains "a", "b", "c"
```

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for Swift 3:

If you want to Add an object at a specific index of a NSMutableArray, use below a simple line of code:

```
self.yourMutableArrayName.insert(<#T##newElement: String##String#>, at: <#T##Int#>)
```

**Example: if you want to add string: "Nature" at index: 3**

```
var str = "Nature"
self.yourMutableArrayName.insert(str, at: 3)
```

// Enjoy..! 